# Trouble on using ActiveModel in order to implement a "Contact Us" form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activemodel

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to implement a "Contact Us" form myself. So...

... in my model file I have:

```
require 'active_model'

class ContactUs
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :email, :subject, :message

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  validates :email,
    :presence   => true

  validates :subject,
    :presence   => true

  validates :message,
    :presence   => true


  def persist
    @persisted = true
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

... in my view file I have:

```
<%= form_for @contact_us, :url => contact_us_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  <%= f.text_area  :message %>
<% end %>
```

... in my router file I have:

```
match 'contact_us' => 'pages#contact_us', :via => [:get, :post]
```

... in my controller file I have:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact_us
    case request.request_method

    when 'GET'
      @contact_us = ContactUs.new

    when 'POST'
      @contact_us = ContactUs.new(params[:contact_us])
    end
  end
end
```

Using the above code, when I submit the form with at least a blank field (I do that in order to make it doesn't pass validations) and the form is reloaded I don't get those fields auto-populated. That is, after reloading the form (this happens after pressing the submit button) field values are set all to blank values.

**What is the problem? Am I wrong on using the `ActiveModel`?**

Comment: Is there a reason you're requiring `active_model` instead of extending `ActiveRecord` ? I'm new to Rails and I've not seen that yet.

Comment: @melee It is from here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/examples/validations.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace

```
<%= form_for @contact_us, :url => contact_us_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
   <%= f.text_field :subject %>
   <%= f.text_area  :message %>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<%= form_for @contact_us, :url => contact_us_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :email, :value => @contact_us.email %>
   <%= f.text_field :subject, :value => @contact_us.subject %>
   <%= f.text_area  :message, :value => @contact_us.message %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

I believe you'll have to add the mass-assigment functionality yourself, like so:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.keys.each do |attr|
    self.class.send(:attr_accessor, attr.to_sym)
    instance_variable_set "@" + attr.to_s, attributes[attr.to_sym]
  end
end
```

You can actually skip this line: `self.class.send(:attr_accessor, attr.to_sym)` if you want to have `attr_accessor :email, :subject, :message` like you do already

Comment: It doesn't work. On submitting the form doesn't seems to fill the '@contact_us = ContactUs.new(params[:contact_us])' data.

Comment: Yes, those are yielded... and too much!!! It happens that also if I fill all fields those errors occour.

Comment: I think the problem is here: `@contact_us = ContactUs.new(params[:contact_us])` or around it. If I debug the `params[:contact_us]` I get the following `--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
email: email@test.com
subject: Test subject
message: Test message`

Comment: OK, now it seams to work. But there is a "standard" way to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think this is pretty much what ActiveRecord does internally, so I would call this way "standard". You could also define each attribute explicitly in the initialize method like: @email = attributes[:email] .. and so on

Comment: Thanks. Just for curiosity: where I can see how ActiveRecord handles things regarding this "attributes initialization"?